# AWS Cognito: Access to Identity is forbidden when calling getOpenIdToken()

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After successfully obtaining a cognito identity, we then try to get an openIdToken()

```
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      var cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
      cognitoIdentity.getOpenIdToken({IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      });

    } else {
      console.log('cognito error: ' + err);
    }
  });
```

However this fails with:

```
"NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxx' is forbidden.
```

Full error trace:

```
    POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
    aws-sdk.min.js:5 [AWS cognitoidentity 400 0.192s 0 retries] getOpenIdToken({IdentityId: 'us-east-1:xxxxx' })
routing.html:64 Error: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxx' is forbidden.
    at a (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:3548)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.callListeners (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:28594)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.emit (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:28390)
    at a.Request.n.emitEvent (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:16483)
    at u.setupStates.e (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:12946)
    at r.runTo (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:7:25031)
    at https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:7:25238
    at null.<anonymous> (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:12982)
    at null.<anonymous> (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:16538)
    at r.SequentialExecutor.r.util.inherit.callListeners (https://www.example.com/bower_components/aws-sdk-js/dist/aws-sdk.min.js:6:28607) "NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxx' is forbidden.
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information such as the code you use to initialize AWS.config.credentials and any other AWS or Cognito code that executes before you call credentials.get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two most common reasons for this error are:

- You haven't setup the roles correctly in the identity pool configuration.
- You are trying to get token for an authenticated identity without providing the token from the identity provider.

Please check your code for both the scenarios above, if error still persists, please PM me your identityId/identityPoolId and I will be happy to dig deeper.

Thanks,

Rachit

Comment: Any chance you could explain what a correct role should look like?  I'm getting this ONLY when I call "refresh".

Comment: Are you using authenticated identities? If yes, what are you passing in the logins map?

Comment: Yes I am.  And I pass in: `logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);` where token is retrieved from `GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount(); String token = account.getIdToken();`

Comment: if this solved the issue can he question poster please explain how did he fix the issue?