# Android AWS Kinesis Video Stream: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxxxx' is forbidden

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams, aws-identitypools

I am trying to connect my app with the AWS Kinesis Video Stream console. I take this aws [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-android.html#producersdk-android-prerequisites) as a reference and try to run this official [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples). But every time I try to stream video, app crashes with a `NotAuthorizedException` exception where `Access to Identity 'us-east-1:xxxx' is forbidden` is the root cause of the issue. This is the logcat crash report.

```
2022-03-04 20:12:03.378 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp E/KinesisVideoAndroidClient: 2022-03-04T20:12Z T2: EXCEPTION: ExecutionException: Awaiting for the credentials update threw an exception: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'us-east-1:0axxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxbff' is forbidden. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 44739d62-17b9-4aef-b88d-bc72a23da744)
2022-03-04 20:12:03.380 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp W/KinesisVideoClientWrapper: getAuthInfo(): Failed to get the object for the AuthInfo object. methodId �
2022-03-04 20:12:03.380 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp W/KinesisVideoClient: createKinesisVideoClient(): operation returned status code: 0x00000002
2022-03-04 20:12:03.380 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp I/KinesisVideoClientWrapper: throwNativeException(): Had to clear a pending exception found when throwing "Failed to create Kinesis Video client." (code 0x2)
2022-03-04 20:12:03.380 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp D/KinesisVideoClientWrapper: throwNativeException(): Throwing com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/producer/ProducerException with message: Failed to create Kinesis Video client.
2022-03-04 20:12:03.394 1034-1034/com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.demoapp E/StreamConfigurationFragment: Failed to create Kinesis Video client
    com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.producer.ProducerException: Failed to create Kinesis Video client. StatusCode: 0x2
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createKinesisVideoClient(Native Method)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.create(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:235)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:247)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.producer.jni.NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.createSync(NativeKinesisVideoProducerJni.java:212)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initializeNewKinesisVideoProducer(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:219)
        at com.amazonaws.kinesisvideo.internal.client.NativeKinesisVideoClient.initialize(NativeKinesisVideoClient.java:136)
```

I also have noticed that somehow `Identity id` is different than mine in logcat. I don't know where this `us-east-1:0axxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxbff` is coming from. This is my `awsconfiguration.json`:

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "us-east-1:5dxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx446",
        "Region": "us-east-1"
      }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
      "AppClientSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...",
      "AppClientId": "xxxxx...",
      "PoolId": "us-east-1_xxxxxxxxx",
      "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
  }
}
```

Part of the code where I initialise KVS and the exception gets thrown:

```
try {
    mKinesisVideoClient = KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(
            getActivity(),
            KinesisVideoDemoApp.KINESIS_VIDEO_REGION,
            KinesisVideoDemoApp.getCredentialsProvider());
} catch (KinesisVideoException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create Kinesis Video client", e);
}
```

getCredentialsProvider():

```
public class KinesisVideoDemoApp extends Application {

    public static Regions KINESIS_VIDEO_REGION = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    public static AWSCredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {
        return AWSMobileClient.getInstance();
    }
    ...
}
```

Initially, as the key is different in logcat I thought the default `AWSMobileClient.getInstance()` is flickering between two identity poles. So I manually tried to access it with the exact key but the result is the same:

```
try {
    mKinesisVideoClient = KinesisVideoAndroidClientFactory.createKinesisVideoClient(
            getActivity(),
            KinesisVideoDemoApp.KINESIS_VIDEO_REGION,
            new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:5dxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx446",
                Regions.US_EAST_1)
    );
} catch (KinesisVideoException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create Kinesis Video client", e);
}
```

As usual, I tried to surf the internet looking for a solution. I take this [SlackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831041/aws-cognito-access-to-identity-is-forbidden-when-calling-getopenidtoken)  and this [Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5696) as a reference and tried all the possible solutions. I make sure:

-> I have the right `user pool id` and `app client id` in my identity `Authentication Provider` `Coginito` section.

-> Cross verified the signed-up user is listed in user pool.

-> Have the right set of roles both the `UnAuth` and `Auth` with right policy in `identity pool` settings.

Nothing really worked for me. Any kind of help is appreciated! Thank you!